# C# code to check in Database scripts to Github repository

Tags: c#, repository

Currently I have a database scripts in specific shared path. I need a c# code which check in the scripts inside the shared path to the Github repository with check in comments.

Note : I have necessary repository details and credentials to connect it.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Put the database scripts within a folder that git is already tracking.  If they're on a shared path for "sharing" reasons, then people should be using the git repo anyway.  This is an X/Y problem.

Comment: Those scripts can't be placed in the folder which git is tracking. It is a separate one.